# iPhone 7 not letting me update to ios11

Tags: ios

My iPhone still isn't offering me the option to update to iOS 11. Why is this? What can I do to let me update? 
I have no clue what to try next any sugustions?

Answer (score 2):

I would take the device to a computer that runs iTunes and update off the air. Check your backups too in case you need to restore instead of upgrade.